# NAudio is not playing 16 bit byte data

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I am trying to play the sound of my acoustic data coming from piezo sensor.

I am %100 sure that the sample rate is 10000Hz the data is 16 bits and mono audio.

This is what I did to play the sound

```
var bytes = analyseModel.AnalyseAcousticSound(commandRetrieveData.Data);

IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                         new MemoryStream(bytes), new WaveFormat(10000, 16, 1));

wo.Init(provider);
wo.Play();
```

if I change the 16 to 8 I am hearing a sound but its just a high pitch buzzing which is not the correct sound and when I change it to 16 I am hearing nothing but getting no error as well.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I used a test audio recording "game.wav" and it plays well with this code, try it.

```
using System;
using NAudio.Wave;

string fileName = "C:\\TMP\\game.wav";

using var reader = new WaveFileReader(fileName);

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                         new MemoryStream(bytes), new WaveFormat(10000, 16, 1));


using (var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent())
{
    waveOut.Init(provider);
    waveOut.Play();
    while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

WAV file I used: https://sendanywhe.re/JPUM3F07
Used on: Windows 64 laptop

So, NAudio can play 16 bit byte data, and I guess it's all about the source of sound or code example.